# Will your pokemon always lose hunger at the same rate?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Because doing mini games and earning puffs takes so long, I would like to know *if the rate at which your pokemon lose hunger can ever be **reduced** so that they will take **longer** to become hungry again.*

If I just feed my pokemon regularly, and will they eventually have a longer full period? Or will they always become hungry at the same rate?

Comment: Wait, different leveled puffs? I really need to pay more attention, I can't just keep going on a question binge like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, hunger rates do not change over time, but higher leveled pokepuffs do fill the pokemon's hunger more than lower leveled ones.

However, if you want to go the other way and make them hungry quicker, you can do so by playing minigames with your Pokemon with Pokemon Amie.

Comment: Sorry, I did think I explained it badly. I'll edit quickly

Comment: Alright, I just added your comment's contents into your answer and accepted it. Feel free to look over it and change anything I got wrong. Thanks!